# How to mock global variable evaluation for multiple tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I need to mock global variable inside a python script.

This variable is initialized using a fairly expensive method which also throws when run outside target environment.

I've found out how to mock this variable once, however subsequent mocks seem not to change the initial one (examples provided).

Script under test:
service/entity/list/src/handler.py

```py
from util.table import get_table

table = get_table('TABLE')

def query_db(event):
    query_args = create_query_params(event)
    query_res = table.query(**query_args)
    return query_res
```

Function I need to mock:
util/table.py

```py
def get_table(table_name):
    return get_db().table(table_name)
```

What I've tried:

1. Mocking where it is used

```py
class TestListEntities(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.event = MagicMock(name='event mock')
        self.table = MagicMock(name='table mock')
        self.query = MagicMock(name='query mock')
        self.query_result = {'items': []}
        self.table.query.return_value = self.query_result

    def test_empty(self):
        with patch('service.entity.list.src.handler.get_table', return_value=self.table):
            from service.entity.list.src.handler import query_db
            response = query_db(self.event)

            self.assertTrue(self.table.query.called)
```

this invokes real method before test even starts.

2. Mocking where it is implemented

```py
    def test_empty(self):
        with patch('util.table.get_table', return_value=self.table):
            from service.entity.list.src.handler import query_db
            response = query_db(self.event)
            self.assertTrue(self.table.query.called)
```

Works as expected, but patches in other test cases do not change this patch and tests fail.

**TL;DR** I need to patch global variable initialization for multiple test cases, but only managed to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import lang_module
from mock import patch
@patch('languages.list', ['EN', 'ES', 'DE'])
class TestLanguages():

    def test_length(self):
        assert 3 == lang_module.get_length()

    def test_contains_lang(self):
       assert lang_module.contains_lang('EN')
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is, to replace the accesses to global variables by getter methods.

For one thing it can help to solve your current problem: You can make the getter method initialize the variable on the first call.  Therefore, if you mock it before the first call, the true initialization function does not get called.

Getter functions also offer more freedom than direct variable accesses in other cases, namely when you want to simulate that the value of the global variable changes between two accesses.  Generally, in contrast to a direct variable access, the call of a function is always a possible point for you to take control.